# I need help correctly inputting an if statement that I can't figure out in excel

Tags: excel

How to I write

if C5 is equal to 1, then display cell d24, if C5 is equal to 2, then sum cell D24 and E24, if C5 is equal is 3, then sum cell D24 through Cell F24,

Comment: `=CHOOSE(C1,D24,D24+E24,SUM(D24:F24))`

Comment: `=SUM(D24:INDEX(24:24,,C1+3))`

Comment: I like that second one.  This is more than a simple one off.  I think it should be an actual answer.

Comment: IIF (Value > 10, Perform this action if Value is <= 10, Perform this action is Value is > 10).  You can nest multiple IIF statements.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the sequence continues, you could use:

```
=SUM(D24:INDEX(24:24,,C1+3))
```

which is equivalent to

1. `=SUM(D24:D24)`
2. `=SUM(D24:E24)`
3. `=SUM(D24:F24)`
4. `=SUM(D24:G24)`

and so on.